# Deployment of .NET Standard assembly (Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client) in 4.6.2 Framework

Tags: c#, deployment, .net-standard-2.0, assembly-binding-redirect, .net-4.6.2

There does not seem to be any particular guidance on what needs to be deployed when consuming a .net standard 2.0 package into the 4.6.2 framework build.

We have a large 4.6.2 project that has one assembly using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client via nuget package. This ends up bringing in netstandard 2.0 and it's huge pile of assemblies to our output folder (100+ assemblies) but the automatic binding redirects written to the config file only list about 64 of them.

My question is do I only need to deploy the ones listed in the .config file tagged with bindingRedirect or do you just deploy all of the extra "shim" assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to build my project with SignalR using the 4.6.2 framework, you must use Package Reference for the SignalR nuget package and you must use Project Settings | Auto-Generate Binding Redirects.
Your output directory will contain the binding redirects needed to run the application. The *.exe.config will have the redirects written out for you (that's nice) but you will find that almost the entire framework gets redirected, feels more like an in-place upgrade using binding redirects.
The code is in production and working well.